# QToolBox looks different then in the designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I'am using QToolBox, and in the application this widget looks different then in the designer. I'am curious, how i can fix it?
OS is ubuntu 14.04 with gnome3.

QToolBox in the app (simple buttons):
[image]

QToolBox in designer (has that fancy lines):
[image]

Comment: Take a look, Dmitrij: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600675/ugly-qt-app-look-under-ubuntu

Comment: Did you ever solve this, @Дмитрий Пузырьков? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: @Thomas, no, i did not solve this. As i understand, the way the widget rendered is depend on the gui-library, which qt is using. The GTK widget by default looks as you see. In link from duDE you can find some advices to change this, but in my case none pof them worked.