# Qt5 ignores setStyle

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

If have the exact same problem [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482641/qtoolbox-looks-different-then-in-the-designer) person was having, except I'm using Qt5.

I tried setting my applications (and my widget's) style sheet by doing this:

```
a_.setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("WindowsVista"));
```

and it compiles fine, but simply ignores the command and shows the usual style. I also made sure that WindowsVista was in the "keys" list.

Is there anything else I might be missing / have to do?

Edit: Forgot to link the thread I was referring to.

Comment: Did you try the static function `QApplication::setStyle("WindowsVista");` before the `QApplication` constructor? The function returns 0 if it can't find the style.

Comment: You could show that it returns the following code: `QStyleFactory::keys()`

Comment: Using that style on any OS that's not Windows at or above Vista version will not work. What is your platform?

Comment: Answering the questions from top to bottom, thanks for your input:
@xander: No, I thought it had to be set afterwards, I will try that.

Comment: @eyllanesc: It does return "WindowsVista" and others that I tried when I call keys(), so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @KubaOber: I added this to the question now, I'm on Windows 7, so it should work

Comment: When asked to clarify, please edit the question and feel free to flag comment asking for it as obsolete. It's not necessary to add the "Edit:" tags as SO keeps a full revision record so you're just trying to manually replicate automation.